# Where does the column decompression happen in TimescaleDB at query time and how does it affect IOPS?

Tags: compression, clickhouse, timescaledb

At query time, does the column decompression in TimescaleDB happen all on disk and we incur the cost of reading all the decompressed data in terms of IOPS ?

If anyone also knows the answer to this for ClickHouse it would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ClickHouse stores data in compressed format and thus reads compressed data. Decompression happens during query execution in RAM.

Comment: Timescale segmentby is used as a strategy to avoid decompress all data during query time. But if you query data that is not in the segment by it will uncompress the chunks of data that satisfies the previous criteria.

Comment: ClickHouse LZ4 is able to decompress 0.5-1GB/s per CPU core. Compression improves performance because it allows to read/write less data and better utilize system page cache and CPU L3/L2.

Comment: @jonatasdp nice, but do you incur IO for reading the compressed bytes only in timescale ?

Comment: @DennyCrane so based on your comment and the answer above, Am i correct to assume this scenario: if i have a query aggregating a SUM() over all records in a 4GB column, the worst case is that Clickhouse will stream the 4GB from disk to RAM and decompress and aggregate as it is streaming the data ? 

i would assume so because decompressing a 4GB column and then aggregating after could end up with data larger than available RAM

Comment: @sm_ It works in streamable manner, using buffers, even if your column 40TB, it will work anyway, using small amount of memory

Comment: Not sure I understood the question @sm_.